# checking and unchecking a RadioButton upon clicking

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I was having some problem when trying to check and uncheck radio button upon click.

What I am trying to do is, when the activity on load, the radio button is set to checked by default. When user pressed on the checked radio button, I set the radio button to uncheck and empty the textview. Then, when the user pressed on the radio button again, I set it to checked and set some text in textview. Here is my code:

```
@Click(R.id.radioButtonEmail)
void radioButtonEmailClicked(View v) {
    if(radioButtonEmail.isChecked() == true){
        radioButtonEmail.setChecked(false);
        editTextEmail.setText("");
    }else {
        radioButtonEmail.setChecked(true);
        editTextEmail.setText("TEST");
    }
}
```

However, this only worked for the first time when I tried to uncheck the radio button. After I set it to false, when I try to check it again, it does not work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: you can straight away use -  if (radioButtonEmail.isChecked())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an exact explanation for the behavior you are seeing, but your logic looks off to me.  I think you intend to do this:

```
@Click(R.id.radioButtonEmail)
void radioButtonEmailClicked(View v) {
    if (radioButtonEmail.isChecked()) {
        editTextEmail.setText("");
    }
    else {
        editTextEmail.setText("TEST");
    }
}
```

In other words, you don't manage whether the radio button is clicked from your event handler.  Rather, you *check* for that state inside the handler, and then respond appropriately.

Comment: But then the radio button will be checked forever no matter how many times I clicked

Comment: Yes, and this is how radio buttons are supposed to behave.  If you want to turn it off, then your user should select some other radio button.  If you instead want a button which can toggle by repeatedly clicking it, then radio button is wrong, and you need some sort of check box widget.

Comment: I see I see thanks! I got confused with radio button and checkbox